# What is the parameter MessageBoxResult defaultResult in MessageBox.Show for?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, messagebox

Some of the MessageBox.Show [overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598707.aspx) has a parameter  MessageBoxResult defaultResult. What is this for? The description says "A MessageBoxResult value that specifies the default result of the message box.". Doesn't the returned MessageBoxResult only depends on what the user clicks/do (see the [remarks here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.messageboxresult.aspx))?

If I want the default behaviour, what value should I pass?

Comment: never knew that option was there.  going to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In plain English, it the option that will be selected if you just hit 'Enter' when the MessageBox appears.

Comment: what if I want the default behaviour?

Comment: Using `MessageBoxResult.None` results in the default behavior.

Comment: I think if you are using an overload that forces you to select a default, you should use common sense to chose the correct default.  After all you are asking the user a question, there is no universal default.  If you are confirming a delete, the default is no, otherwise predominantly  I tend to the positive. you need to think 'what is the default behaviour for THIS SCENARIO?' -- Its the 'preferred' choice more so that the default, if that helps you decide

Comment: @Rick didnt know that, I still think the dev should have to make a decision at this point. 'default' is subjective in some cases.

Comment: I want to use the MessageBoxOptions options parameter, and all overloads that take that parameter also take MessageBoxResult defaultResult. What I mean by default is, the value that is use when I don't specify that parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As per [MSDN Documentation on DialogResult Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult.aspx), this is specifying the return value of the message box.

Possible values are :

- **None**  : Nothing is returned from the dialog box. This means that the modal dialog continues running.
- **OK** :  The dialog box return value is OK (usually sent from a button labeled OK).
- **Cancel** : The dialog box return value is Cancel (usually sent from a button labeled Cancel).
- **Abort** : The dialog box return value is Abort (usually sent from a button labeled Abort).
- **Retry** : The dialog box return value is Retry (usually sent from a button labeled Retry).
- **Ignore** :  The dialog box return value is Ignore (usually sent from a button labeled Ignore).
- **Yes**   : The dialog box return value is Yes (usually sent from a button labeled Yes).
- **No** :  The dialog box return value is No (usually sent from a button labeled No).

And based on [MSDN Documentation on MessageBox.Show method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/519bytz3.aspx), the default button for a message box would be the **OK** button.

Meaning if you did not specify any button on a message box, it will always have an OK button in order to close it. So the "default behavior" or default value returned by a message box would be to check the DialogResult.OK

```
result = MessageBox.Show(message);

if(result == DialogResult.OK) { /* default or OK button has been pressed */ }
```

Comment: what if there is no OK button?

Comment: If you don't specify any MessageBoxButtons parameter there will always be an OK button by default, so your default value will be DialogResult.OK. Then I guess if you specify some MessageBoxButtons parameter value, your DialogResult value should be part of the MessageBoxButtons.
Again if you want to stick to default MessageBox.Show, you should consider using the OK value.